# Google Managed VMs data volume

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, google-compute-engine

How do I keep data on my Managed VMs using docker ?

I'm following this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/getting-started), so I guess that the `volumes` [property from containers engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/pods/operations) is not available.

Like this: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

Comment: what did you try? Compute Engine or Container Engine?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I edited my answer, now there's a link with the guide I'm following. Which is Managed VM (From App Engine), so I guess is neither Container ou Compute engine. (Actually I think is computer engine)

Comment: oh, didn't thought about Managed VM. As I know this kind of VMs doesn't have real disk, just ephemeral space, initialized on each restart. so writing to a volume will be useless I guess